# Retrieve console log from a nested job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a Matrix job (Job A) with that call build  sub job (B) using Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin.

In the Parent Job (Mtrix) i use Editable Email Notification to trigger each configuration.

I want to get 15 lines from child job (B) build log  for each configuration to add it in the email (if the build fails).

How can I do such thing ?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allows you to configure every aspect of email notifications. You can customize when an email is sent, who should receive it, and what the email says.

here is the link : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin